# How can I allow users to submit q queries and interpret them as a string?

Tags: kdb

I want to allow users to write real q queries like

`select from table where date=.z.d`

Is it possible to use something like

`E)select from table where date=.z.d`

and then use the input to that `E)` to parse the query and do stuff with it?

Comment: Are all of your users queries coming in from remote instances and/or IDEs? If so then your `.z.pg` handler can most likely handle the queries and do what you like with them. Or do all your users have their own local instance and you want control over those queries to local instances?

Comment: So I am asking because I have seen something similar in the past, but I can't find it on the KX website anymore. 
Let's say you spawn a kdb client and the user wants to write queries like normal qsql instead of running an api with a dictionary of params. 
I think I have seen it like `M)`

Comment: https://code.kx.com/q/wp/query-interface/

Answer (score 3):

If you create a function called `.E.e`, anything you pass to it will be interpreted as a string, so you can do something like this to start parsing your input:

```
q).E.e: {" " vs x}
q)E)select from table where date = .z.d
"select"
"from"
"table"
"where"
"date"
,"="
".z.d"
```

Comment: **Watch Out** All single-character namespaces are [reserved for use by KX](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/namespaces/).